# play framework cookies cors

Tags: cookies, cors, playframework-2.3

now I am using play framework 2.3, how to share cookie on cors (cross domain)
i have play application on port localhost:9000 and i want to share cookies to my client running on localhost:5000
client cannt get the cookies 
i try with this in play framework app:

```
response().setCookie(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken); //with setting on application.conf (session.domain="http://localhost:5000") cookies sent but cannt read by javascipt /failed
response().setCookie(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken,10000,"localhost:5000","/"); //fail
response().setCookie(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken,10000,"127.0.0.1:5000","/*"); //fail
response().setCookie(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken,10000,"127.0.0.1:5000","/*"); //fail
```

and this is response on chrome :

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9000
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/common/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:33
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http://localhost:5000
Referer:http://localhost:5000/index-login.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
username:adilramdan
password:1234
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-AUTH-TOKEN
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:52
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie:authToken=8cd7d5cc-600a-42a0-ab79-d7ff2b4f71b0; Expires=Tue, 15 Jul 2014 02:30:09 GMT; Path=/
```

<------COOKIES IS AVAILABLE ON RESPONSE SERVER BUT JAVA SCRIPT CLIENT SAY NO COOKIES FOUND

how the right way?
 any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header. If you are using AJAX/JQuery you must set

```
withCredentials = true
```

In your request. The server must also respond with header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Note that if you do this you must specify a value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. The browser will not accept `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header while `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a wildcard.

See the resources here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/